# Can't set UUID primary key on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jrubyonrails

Old code, works fine in Rails 3.0 on JRuby 1.6.4 with PostgreSQL 9.0:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_validation(:on => :create) do
        self.id = generate_random_uuid
    end

    # Mode code, including a definition for generate_random_uuid that works.
end
```

Rails 3.1 silently fails to set the primary key.

Did a bit of digging, and came up with `update_column`, but this refuses to do anything until the record has been persisted. Unfortunately, not too many people are using UUID primary keys in Rails-land, so the Googles aren't that useful.

Anybody else running a similar setup, that's figured out the right callback magic to get 3.1 to play ball?

Comment: hey, could you show your schema? have you generated your table with :id => false, and added a custom :id column by your own?

Comment: Yep, custom :id column. Like I said, code worked just fine under Rails 3.0, but they made a *lot* of changes to the persistence layer in 3.1. It's also worth noting that I can go into `rails console`, create a new instance, set the ID by hand in the console, and save it with no problem. It just doesn't seem to fly in a callback, which is massively irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well..only just today noticed, that an app involving several legacy databases had stopped working after upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1 just for this reason, i.e. the primary key doesn't default to id anymore for legacy databases (and the like?).

My so far working solution was to explicitly give a

```
set_primary_key :id
```

in each of the models in question.

Regards
Michael